# Android - CollapsingToolbarLayout elevation shadow disappears when setting exitUntilCollapsed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I'm using a custom AppBarLayout because I want a custom shape for my toolbar with an elevation shadow.   The background is set on the AppBarLayout as a custom Drawable and I use the following code to to get the shadow to render on the toolbar.

```
setClipToOutline(true);
setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
```

All is good, the shadow renders. However, my CollapsingToolbarLayout also contains some tabs and when I collapse the toolbar I want my tabs to stay visible. Currently when I scroll the entire toolbar disappears including the tabs ands it's only when I set exitUntilCollapse on the CollapsingToolbarLayout that the tabs remain after scrolling.  The catch is when I set this flag my elevation shadow stops rendering!  Why could this be? Is there a way around it, is there another way to stop my tabs disappearing?

I've included some of my relevant layout code below:

```
    <com.ss.views.CustomBackgroundAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_behavior="com.ss.views.FlingBehaviour"
        >


      <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
          android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="0dp"
          app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="0dp"
          app:expandedTitleMarginStart="0dp"
          app:expandedTitleMarginTop="0dp"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
          app:titleEnabled="false"
          >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            layout="@layout/include_tab_layout"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:minHeight="100dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />

        <include
          android:id="@+id/user_dash"
          app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
          layout="@layout/include_toolbar_user_dash"/>

      </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </com.ss.views.CustomBackgroundAppBarLayout>
```

Comment: A little update, I've hacked my way out of this for now by removing the tablayout from the toolbar and sitting it on the top so that it never gets removed from the screen.  Then I don't need exist until collapsed.